# WordPress/Woocommerce Inline Javascript adding Nonce and CSP not working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have been trying to add a Nonce to inline JS in Wordpress primarily focusing on WooCommerce. So far, I've managed to add the Nonce to registered JS but the inline JS code generated out of plugins such as Woocommerce isn't getting the Nonce added.

The approach which has worked for registered JS is...

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_nonce_to_script2', 10, 3 );

function add_nonce_to_script2( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
    global $my_nonce2;
    $my_nonce2 = wp_create_nonce('my__script__nonce');
    return '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . esc_url( $src ) . '" nonce="nonce-' . esc_attr( $my_nonce2 ) . '"></script>';
}
```

The approach which isn't working, maybe because I don't know the right $var for data to pass to the below solution from Woocommerce, any guidance would be appreciated.

Example code I'm trying to target.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var wc_add_to_cart_params = {"ajax_url":"\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","wc_ajax_url":"\/?wc-ajax=%%endpoint%%","i18n_view_cart":"View cart","cart_url":"https:\/\/mysite.com\/cart\/","is_cart":"","cart_redirect_after_add":"no"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Solution that isn't working below...

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_nonce_to_script_tag', 10, 3 );

function add_nonce_to_script_tag( $tag, $handle, $src ) {

  // Check the $handle and respond accordingly
  if ( $handle === 'my-script' ) {
    $nonce_value = wp_create_nonce('my__script__nonce'); // or ref to an existing nonce
    $replace = sprintf("javascript' nonce='%s'>", $nonce_value );
    $tag = str_replace( "javascript'>", $replace, $tag);
  }

  return $tag;
}

// Then... $data is the inline JS from wherever
wp_add_inline_script('my-script', $data, 'before');
```

Comment: Check it please - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/231797/what-is-nonce-and-how-to-use-it-with-ajax-in-wordpress

Comment: @Dmitry that is about the WP nonce, the question here is about a nonce in the context of CSP - completely different thing.

Comment: Thanks for the help Dmitry, but in this case I think wp_add_inline_script is the way to go for inline but I need to know what $var I should be passing over to wp_add_inline_script('my-script', $data, 'before'); for Woocommerce. Maybe the class-wc-frontend-scripts.php file is where the code is coming from, but I'm not sure and need some help narrowing it down.